# How do I ensure that my 2D side-scroller camera stays within the world bounds?

Tags: xna, camera, monogame, platformer, side-scroller

I have tried implementing a basic 2D sidescroller camera in XNA, but I don't want it to be able to scroll past the edges of my tile map!

I tried to fix it, but when I get the left side working, the right stops working...

How do I do this right?

EDIT: After Anko

```
public Matrix transform;    
Viewport view; 
Vector2 center; 

public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Player player) {
    center = new Vector2(player.Position.X + (player.Bounds.Width / 2) - (960 / 2), 0);

    float cameraX = center.X;
    float cameraWidth = view.Width;

    float worldWidth = 1760;

    if (cameraX < 0) 
        cameraX = 0;
    else if  ( cameraX + cameraWidth > worldWidth)
        cameraX = worldWidth - cameraWidth;

    transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-cameraX, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Just checking: Roughly how are you implementing a camera? Are you applying a translation to the view when your game is rendered or are you moving all objects around?

Comment: I tried applying a translation using a view matrix. And hey, you were the one who helped me with the guns! Got that working quite nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's draw it! <sub>([Again](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70145/how-do-i-make-a-2d-character-aim-their-gun-toward-the-mouse) ;3)</sub>

[image: game world, with camera]

Imagine all the grassy and skyey bits are your game world. That lighter coloured rectangle framed in red is the region the camera is looking at. A player would only actually see what's in the camera. We want the camera to always stay in the game world.

`(x,y)` is the camera position

`w` and `h` are the camera's width and height

Let's also say your game world has width `world_w` and height `world_h`.

To take care of left, we want to ensure `x > 0`

To take care of right, we want to ensure `x + w < world_w`

To take care of the top, we want to ensure `y > 0`

To take care of bottom, we want to ensure `y + h < world_h`

So, before you apply a transformation matrix to translate by `x, y`, check that our assumptions indeed are true, and if not, correct them so they just about are:

```
if x < 0 then
    x = 0
elseif x + w > world_w
    x = world_w - w

if y < 0 then
    y = 0
elseif y + h > world_h
    y = world_h - h
```

No more escaping camera!

Note that you might want to build in a special case to detect if your world is smaller than your camera, if such a tiny world might happen in your game.

Comment: It works! There's something I'm confused about though, so maybe you can catch where something is off. I assumed view.Width is getting the camera width, but I'm not sure what it actually does. :P So my worldWidth should actually be 64px tiles * 30 columns = 1920. When I tried this value for worldWidth, it actually went off the right edge. I just kept lowering the value until I found that 1760 worked perfectly. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: @Tidus Yey! :D I don't know what `view.Width` exactly means in your code, so I can't really help with that. (Also, debugging questions are off-topic here.) To [debug a C# program](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_debugging.html), you could call [`Trace.WriteLine`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788) inside those `if`s to write the variables' values to the console and see for yourself what they are and if they're making sense.